# Meteor 1.4. AutoForm validation message not showing

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform, simple-schema, meteor-collection2

1. I've added autoform packege (meteor add aldeed:autoform)
2. I've added collection2-core packege (meteor add collection2-core)
3. I've installed simpl-schema (npm i --save simpl-schema)
   But form still does not working correctly

/imports/api/rooms/rooms.js

```
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker';
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
SimpleSchema.extendOptions(['autoform']);

export const Rooms = new Mongo.Collection('rooms');

Rooms.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Title'
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Description'
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        autoValue(){
            return new Date();
        }
    },
}), {tracker: Tracker});
```

/imports/ui/pages/home.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';

import './home.html';

import { Rooms } from '../../api/rooms/rooms.js'

Template.Home.helpers({
    rooms() {
        return Rooms.find({});
    },
    CollectionRooms() {
        return Rooms;
    }
});
```

/imports/ui/pages/home.html

```
<template name="Home">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container text-center">
            <h1>Forum</h1>
            <p>“Don't raise your voice, improve your argument."</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid bg-3">
        <h3 class="page-header">Choose your room</h3>

        {{> quickForm collection=CollectionRooms id="insertRoomsForm" type="insert"}}

        <div class="row grid-divider">
        {{#each rooms}}
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="col-padding">
                    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
                    <p>{{desc}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

packages

```
meteor-base@1.0.4             # Packages every Meteor app needs to have
mobile-experience@1.0.4       # Packages for a great mobile UX
mongo@1.1.17                   # The database Meteor supports right now
blaze-html-templates@1.0.4 # Compile .html files into Meteor Blaze views
reactive-var@1.0.11            # Reactive variable for tracker
tracker@1.1.3                 # Meteor's client-side reactive programming library

standard-minifier-css@1.3.4   # CSS minifier run for production mode
standard-minifier-js@2.0.0    # JS minifier run for production mode
es5-shim@4.6.15                # ECMAScript 5 compatibility for older browsers.
ecmascript@0.7.3              # Enable ECMAScript2015+ syntax in app code
shell-server@0.2.3            # Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command

autopublish@1.0.7             # Publish all data to the clients (for prototyping)
insecure@1.0.7                # Allow all DB writes from clients (for prototyping)
twbs:bootstrap
iron:router
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2-core
```

I see the form and it inserts record into database, but validation message not showing and why there is field "created at"? what I'm doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: Can you try doing `AutoForm.debug()` and then resubmitting the form and see if there's an error

Comment: What validation message are you expecting it to show? If you submit a blank form, what is getting stored in the DB? Secondly, ```createdAt``` is being shown because it's specified in the schema by you. If you need it to be a hidden field, then use: ```createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        autoValue(){
            return new Date();
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    }```

Comment: @blueren thanks for help to figure out with autoValue, I thought it makes field hidden by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a typo in your Schema, which causes the Tracker not been included. This in the end causes your form to not have (reactive) validation messages. The corrected code is:

```
Rooms.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Title'
    },
    desc: {
        type: String,
        label: 'Description'
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        autoValue(){
            return new Date();
        }
    },
}, {tracker: Tracker}));
```

Comment: thanks, yes you are right the programming makes people blind). I've wasted a tons of time. You've saved my life)